# importing values of a python dictionary as data to an existing mysql table

Tags: python, mysql

I have problem with storing values of a python dictionary as data to an existing mysql table

I tried to use the code below but it's not working.

```
db = mysql.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="123456",
    database="tgdb"
)
cursor = db.cursor()
val = ', '.join("'" + str(x) + "'" for x in dict.values())
sql = "INSERT INTO tgdb.channel(user_name, image_url, name, 
number_of_members, description, channel_url)  VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, 
%s)"
cursor.execute(sql, val)
db.commit()
print(cursor.rowcount, "record inserted.")


"you have an error in your SQL syntax"
```

Comment: Unless the `mysql` library differs extremely in how "prepared statements" gets executed by `execute`, you're most likely supposed to supply a list, not a string as `val`. Meaning, instead of doing `val = ', '.join()` just do, `val = list(dict.values())`. or probably just `cursor.execute(sql, dict.values())` for short :)

Comment: it works , really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As writed @Torxed shouldn't translate dict in string, you can write just that:

```
cursor.execute(sql, list(dict.values())
```